# Will any version of QTP with any available extentions support Telerik's controls for ASP.NET MVC apps

Tags: qtp, telerik

Could you pls share your experience if you have evere tried to automate ASP.NET MVC application testing with QTP , if this web site uses telerik extensions for asp.net mvc3 extensivly.

Yes we know that Telerik has its own test automation tool, but our customers has QTP licences and wants to utilize it.

Are there any 3rd party extensions or products that improves QTP vs Telerik compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of searching, it does not look like there is any QTP support for those controls. You can however develop your own extensibility plugins to work with them. Check out QTP's help files for more info on how to do this.

Comment: i think QTP loses the market of web UI testing by ignoring most popular web UI frameworks